# Amazon Simple Email Service SMTP using PHP Mailer

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services

I finally find the solution of my problem, i post new codes that work properly. I have a new issue now, let say that my email has more than one destination, when i try to put many email adresses in **$to variable**. For exemple **$to="abc@gmail.com,pat@gmail.com";** it's not working but with only one it's worked. How can i do it with more than one address ?

```
$account="username";
 $password="password";
  $to="abc@gmail.com";
 $from="efb@gmail.com";
 $from_name="name";
 $msg="<strong>test smtp with amazon.</strong>"; // HTML message
 $subject="HTML message";
 require 'class.phpmailer.php';

  $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->Host = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
 $mail->SMTPAuth= true;
 $mail->Port = 465; 
 $mail->Username= $account;
$mail->Password= $password;
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
 $mail->From = $from;
 $mail->FromName= $from_name;
 $mail->isHTML(true);
 $mail->Subject = $subject;
  $mail->Body = $msg;
  $mail->addAddress($to);

  if(!$mail->send()){
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  }else{
  echo "E-Mail has been sent";
   }
```

Comment: What server OS are you using Ubuntu or Linux?

Comment: None of them, just working on windows

Comment: Is the Windows SMTP port open ?

Answer (score 1):

As u are using gmail u should less secure your app using this link after login to gmail.
link: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

host should be $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; for gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Do you completed validate e-mail abc@gmail.com ? First you must go to

[> https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/)

Then in Email Addresses checked there is your abc@gmail.com address. If no click on Verify a New Email Address and add one. You'll get test message. After that in Verified Sender: Email row you will see next to your e-mail the green world "verified".

Comment: i just replaced abc@gmail.com by a verifed sender email  wich  has a green word ''verified'' status. it still not working, i even host my codes, it still not working

Comment: Since i did follow your advice and it still not working, do you know something else i can do ?

Comment: try send e-mail to this address through another method. Telnet for example. Maybe it doesn't work.

Comment: I resolve my problem i just edited my first post, have a look on the new issue i have. Sending email to several addresses.

Answer (score 0):

For adding more than one email you can do it in the following way:

```
$mail->AddAddress("prodip@cottonist.org");
$mail->AddAddress("srasel84@yahoo.com");
$mail->AddAddress("abid@cottonist.org");
```